# indexing jsonb fields with sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

How can I index field that I needed in jsonb fields with sunspot?
I have the model Man:

```
 #<Man id: 1, name: "John Doe", type: "Man", r_id: "5734", fields: {"message"=>"hello world!", "sex"=>2, "uid"=>5734, "domain"=>"www.old-man.com"}, created_at: "2018-07-12 12:44:07", updated_at: "2018-07-12 12:44:07">
```

So, I'm trying to indicate searchable fields like this:

```
  searchable do
      text :fields, stored: true
    end
```

and it will index all fields. 
But how to indicate only field "message" in fields as a searchable field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From gem [documentation](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot):

```
searchable do
  text :title, :body
  text :comments do
    comments.map { |comment| comment.body }
  end
  ...
end
```

That doesn't work for you?

```
searchable do
  text :fields do
    fields["message"]
  end
end
```

Comment: fields.select { |k, _v|  fields[k] if searchable_fields_arr.include? k } helps %)